# SQL JOIN with condition on second table with sequelizejs

Tags: mysql, join, sequelize.js

I have the following models:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: Sequelize.TEXT,
    avatar: Sequelize.TEXT,
});

const Event = sequelize.define('event', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    timestamp: Sequelize.DATE,
});

const EventUser = sequelize.define('event_user', {});

Event.hasMany(EventUser);
EventUser.belongsTo(User);
```

So `EventUser` holds my list of participants for a specific event.

I'm trying to query for all events where user X is participating:

```
let events = await Event.findAll({
    include: [
        {model: EventUser, include: [{model: User, where: {id: 1}}]}
    ],
});
```

But it won't fetch the list of other participants for that event. Not sure how to achieve that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way is to define many-to-many relation between Users and Events

```
User.belongsToMany(Event, {through: 'EventUser'});
Event.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'EventUser'});
```

Then, you can get all events of some user like this:

```
User.findById(userId).then(function(user){
    return user.getEvents();
}).then(function(events){
    //here's events
});
```

Or through one query:

```
Event.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: User,
        where: {id: userId}
    }]
}).then(function(events){
    //here's events
});
```

Comment: The one query option doesn't work (it returns only that user as a participants - not all of them), but the first option works great, thanks!